# Eiffel: how to use old keyword in ensure contract clause with detached

Tags: eiffel

How to use the `old` keyword into `ensure` clause of a feature, the current statement doesn't seem to be valid at runtime

```
relationships: CHAIN -- any chain

some_feature
    do
    (...)
    ensure
        relationship_added: attached relationships as l_rel implies
            attached old relationships as l_old_rel and then
            l_rel.count = l_old_rel.count
    end
```

### For the whole case, following screenshots demonstrate the case

start of routine execution
[image]
end of routine execution
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't seem to be valid"? What version of the compiler do you use? (The code compiles fine by EiffelStudio 18.11.)

Comment: I also have this version, it compiles but doesn't validate on runtime, with this semantic how would you write it?

Comment: Would you describe what you expect and what you get, please?

Comment: Thx again for your help, I expect to create a statement which makes me able to validate that relationships has grown from 1 on ensure. The statement as written above is False even if it has grown ...

Comment: @AlexanderKogtenkov added some screenshots, hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 cases to consider: when the original reference is `void`, and when — not:

```
attached relationships as r implies r.count =
    old (if attached relationships as o then o.count + 1 else 1 end)
```

The intuition behind the assertion is as follows:

1. If `relationships` is `Void` on exit, we do not care about `count`.
2. If `relationships` is attached on exit, it has one more item compared to the old value. The old value may be attached or `Void`:

   - if the old value is attached, the new number of items is the old number plus `1`;
   - if the old value is `Void`, the new number of items is `1`.

Comment: Does that really work? Don't you need to `twin` the "old" relationship, otherwise it's the same object as the contemporary one and therefore they would have the same count.

Comment: @EricBezault Indeed, I've corrected the code accordingly.

Comment: Seems pretty cryptic for me... to what the old does refer to in evaluation of your statement between parenthesis? either "new" relationships.count + 1 or 1? I'd like to compare relationships.count with old relationships.count don't I?

Comment: According to your point, the new following statement would be v valid? compilation succeds, but runtime complains on `relationships_added_old_attached``relationship_added_old_void: not attached old relationships_from_data implies
    attached relationships_from_data as l_new_rel and then l_new_rel.count = 1
   relationships_added_old_attached: attached old relationships_from_data as l_old_rel implies
    attached relationships_from_data as l_new_rel and then
    l_new_rel.count = l_old_rel.count + 1`

Comment: @Pipo As pointed out by Eric, you would need to use `twin` in this code, because `old relationships_from_data` and `relationships_from_data` is the same reference. The code in the answer has the semantics you are looking for, but is much more concise and efficient.

Comment: @Pipo I've extended the answer with an explanation.